# UISplitView with header programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift

-------------Navigation-----------

-------------Extra View------------

--Master View-- | --Detail View--

See image: [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieKEq.png)

I am working in Swift 1.2 and I am looking to create the above layout within my application.

Within a `UINavigationController`, I want to contain a `UISplitViewController`, and above that `UISplitController` I want a header view that stretches across both the Master and Detail view controllers.

Within this view I'll be creating a search bar, with advanced search options. I'll want to be able to edit the height of this extra view, so that it can effectively push down the `UISplitViewController`.

What is the best way of achieving this programmatically? Is this something that I should do using containers (they're not actually something I've ever used before)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a UINavigationController with a root view controller of type UIViewController. This gives you your navigation bar. You could however just add a navigation bar to a UIViewController if all you want is a top bar.

In this UIViewController, add a view pinned to the top, leading and trailing and give it a height. This is your search area in your diagram.

Then add a container view to put your split view controller in. You want to pin the top of this to the search view, leading and trailing and bottom to the controllers view.

Add your UISplitViewController as a child controller of this container view.

This gives you what you have in your diagram.

This is very simple to do in storyboard in minutes. To do it in code, you will need to look at the documentation for how to add a child controller. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

**Update: Try the following code in you UIViewController:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create top and bottom views
    UIView *topView=[[UIView alloc] init];
    UIView *bottomView=[[UIView alloc] init];

    // Stop constraints being auto generatyed.
    [topView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [bottomView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    // Set the colors so we can see the views.
    [topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [bottomView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    // Add the two views
    [self.view addSubview:topView];
    [self.view addSubview:bottomView];

    //
    // Add constraints.
    //

    // Constraint dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *viewDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:topView, @"topView",bottomView,@"bottomView", nil];

    NSLayoutFormatOptions options;

    // Pin leading and trailing of top view
    NSArray *constraints=
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[topView]|"
                                                options:options
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewDictionary
         ];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    // Pin leading and trailing of bottom view
    constraints=
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bottomView]|"
                                            options:options
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:viewDictionary
     ];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    // Pin top view to top, give it height 100, pin bottom to bottom view and bottom
    // view to bottom.
    constraints=
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topView(100)][bottomView]|"
                                            options:options
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:viewDictionary
     ];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    //
    // Add Split View Controller as child.
    //

    // Left hand split view controller Temp for now.
    UIViewController *left=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
    left.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    // Right hand split view detail contreoller. Temp for now.
    UIViewController *right=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
    right.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    // Create split view with left and right
    UISplitViewController *splitView=[[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitView.viewControllers=@[left,right];

    // Add as a child controller to the bottom view
    [self addChildViewController:splitView];
    [bottomView addSubview:splitView.view];

    // Add constraints for split view.
    viewDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:splitView.view,
                    @"splitView",nil];

    // Pin all sides to the container.
    constraints=
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[splitView]|"
                                                options:options
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewDictionary
         ];
    [bottomView addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints=
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[splitView]|"
                                                options:options
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewDictionary
     ];
    [bottomView addConstraints:constraints];

    // Complete contract for adding child controller.
    [splitView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, that helps. 

I will probably end up doing this in the storyboard, but if I were to do it programmatically. 

I'm happy creating the UINavigationController, adding the UIViewController and adding a view.

I'm not sure I understand how you create a container view programmatically? Is it as simple as using addChildViewController within the UIViewController added above?

Comment: For a container view programmatically, I think you just create a normal UIView with constraints pinning it to where you want it. In storyboard, there is a separate view for the job. Then you follow the steps in the link I put in the answer: Add child controller to the main controller, set the child controllers frame to your container views frame, add the child controllers view into your container view as a subview and then finally call `didMoveToParentViewController` on the child. You can add constraints for the child controllers view after you have added it.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I've been trying to do this for hours now and I've not been having any luck. I don't suppose you have any example code?

I want to do this programmatically so I absolutely understand every step that is being taken.

I am creating a UIViewController that sits within the UINavigationController, that is fine. I have then added a view to the view controller by using VC.view.addview(topView), but then how do I add the bottom view? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry no example handy. For your views, you are adding 2 separate views: one under the other. For hand coding using Visual Format Language makes things easier for defining constraints: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-visual-format-language--cms-22715. So I would create 2 views and add them as subviews. Then use VFL to assign the constraints. Top view needs left, top and trailing pinned to `self.view` and a height. The bottom view needs pinned leading, trailing and bottom to `self.view` and its top pinned to the bottom of the top view. The bottom is your child container.

Comment: @BrianMarsh Added working code for you. Put this in your root UIViewController of your navigation controller. I have added colors so you can see the layout.

Comment: @BrianMarsh Replace `left` and `right` in the code with what you want the master and detail controllers of the split view to be. I've just used UIViewControllers with different background colors so you can see it is working for now.

Comment: Hello Rory, thanks for this. I'm actually using Swift 1.2 but hopefully it won't take too long to convert ;-)

Comment: @BrianMarsh Ah, sorry never realized. Should have looked at the subject tag 8^(. This code works, so hopefully easy enough to port.

Comment: Rory, that has worked perfectly. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm actually getting a constraint error. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rory:

```
let topView = UIView()
let bottomView = UIView()

topView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
bottomView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

self.view.addSubview(topView)
self.view.addSubview(bottomView)

var viewDictionary = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("topView", topView),("bottomView", bottomView))

var options = NSLayoutFormatOptions()

var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[topView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)

self.view.addConstraints(constraints)

constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bottomView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)

self.view.addConstraints(constraints)

constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[topView(100)][bottomView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)

self.view.addConstraints(constraints)

let left = UIViewController()
left.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

let right = UIViewController()
right.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

let splitView = UISplitViewController()

splitView.viewControllers = [left, right]

self.addChildViewController(splitView)
bottomView.addSubview(splitView.view)

viewDictionary = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("splitView", splitView.view))

constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[splitView]|", options: options, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)

bottomView.addConstraints(constraints)

constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[splitView]|",options: options, metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)

bottomView.addConstraints(constraints)
splitView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

// I'm getting this error now for some reason.

```
2015-10-12 18:20:13.417 GPSApp[36430:478129] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7981a8c0 H:|-(0)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x7981c100]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7983e5e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7981a860 H:[UILayoutContainerView:0x7981c100]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7983e5e0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79815350 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x7981c100.midX == UIView:0x7983e5e0.midX + 512>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7981a860 H:[UILayoutContainerView:0x7981c100]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7983e5e0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-10-12 18:20:13.419 GPSApp[36430:478129] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7981a270 V:|-(0)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x7981c100]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7983e5e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7981a220 V:[UILayoutContainerView:0x7981c100]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7983e5e0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x798153b0 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x7981c100.midY == UIView:0x7983e5e0.midY + 384>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7981a220 V:[UILayoutContainerView:0x7981c100]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7983e5e0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: fixed with splitView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)